# Eucalyptus set up issue while uploading an image

Tags: linux, eucalyptus

I followed the following link for installing Eucalyptus cloud environment on CentOS 6.2 http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=eucalyptus.

I am getting the following error when trying to upload an image :

[root@Cloud centos-6.3-x86_64]# euca-upload-bundle -b centos-kernel-bucket -m /tmp/vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64.manifest.xml
Checking bucket: centos-kernel-bucket
timed out

I tried in many forums and could not get correct any solution to the above error. Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks,
Anil kottam.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's a fairly good chance that one or more of your services aren't running.

Try running "euca-describe-services" and if you see any which are *not* ENABLED, you would need to resolve that before having a good experience.

Having said that, I would encourage you to try out the Cloud-in-a-Box solution. You'll want to be running CentOS 6.6 before proceeding:

https://www.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus-cloud/get-started